# How to make p elements positioned at different places responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have positioned `<p>` elements at different places on a web-page.However, these elements gets on top of each other on the mobile browser. how can I make these elements responsive when they are accessed from mobile browser ? 
for more details, check the blue box on this website: 
http://www.cbssolutions.co.uk/software-development/

```
      <div class="con">
         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <div class="servive-block servive-block-dark-blue">            
                    <i class="icon-2x color-light fa fa-gift"></i>
                    <h3 class="heading-md">Welcome</h3>           
                    <p class="p1">Element1</p>      
                     <p class="p2">Element2</p>
                         <p class="p3">Element3</p>
                         <p class="p4">Element4</p> 
               </div>
            </div>      
               </div>     <!-- End Of Row -->
           </div>     <!-- End Of Container -->


.servive-block {
  padding: 40px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
.con {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;     
}


.servive-block h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.servive-block h3a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.servive-block-light,
.servive-block-default {
  background: #fafafa;
  border: solid 1px #eee; 
}

.servive-block-default:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #eee;
}

.servive-block-dark-blue {
  background: #4765a0;

.p1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 120px;
    left: 60px;    
}
.p2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
     left: 60px;
}
.p3{
     position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 1000px;
}
.p4{

     position: absolute;
    bottom: 120px;
    left: 1000px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using a framework like bootstrap. If you use bootstrap your code would look like this :

```
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
             <i class="icon-2x color-light fa fa-gift"></i>
                <h3 class="heading-md">Welcome</h3>   
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
             <p class="p1">Element1</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
             <p class="p1">Element2</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
             <p class="p1">Element3</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
             <p class="p1">Element4</p>
           </div>
           </div>     <!-- End Of Row -->
       </div>     <!-- End Of Container -->
```

Here's a link to a working jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3h44eh4z/

Comment: Make sure you add the bootstrap css and js links to your page in order for it to work right.